# what are some lines meaning in magento.?

Tags: php, magento

Supposed there is a function in a \AW\Blog\Model\post.php.there is a function in it.

```
public function PreNext($type){
    $id = $this->_data['post_id'];
    $blog = Mage::getResourceModel('blog/post_collection');

        $blog->getSelect()->where('post_id>?',$id);

    return $blog->getFirstItem();
}
```

why it write `$this->_data['post_id'];` could i write it with another.
what are the four lines meaning which in the function within magento.? many thanks.

the post.php

```
class AW_Blog_Model_Post extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract{

    const NOROUTE_PAGE_ID = 'no-route';

    protected function _construct(){
        $this->_init('blog/post');
    }

    public function load($id, $field=null){
        return $post = parent::load($id, $field);
    }

    public function noRoutePage(){
        $this->setData($this->load(self::NOROUTE_PAGE_ID, $this->getIdFieldName()));
        return $this;
    }

    public function getShortContent(){
        $content = $this->getData('short_content');
        if(Mage::getStoreConfig(AW_Blog_Helper_Config::XML_BLOG_PARSE_CMS)){
            $processor = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_filter');
            $content = $processor->filter($content);
        }
        return $content;
    }

    public function getPostContent(){
        $content = $this->getData('post_content');
        if(Mage::getStoreConfig(AW_Blog_Helper_Config::XML_BLOG_PARSE_CMS)){
            $processor = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_filter');
            $content = $processor->filter($content);
        }
        return $content;
    }

    public function loadByIdentifier($v) {
        return $this->load($v, 'identifier');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is code of a custom extension, so only people having this extension can know, what this `post.php` file contains, and whether you can get the value using other ways than `$this->_data['post_id']`.

If the extension uses standard Magento Getters/Setters, maybe `$this->getPostId()` may work, too.

The rest loads a collection of records having a `post_id` greater than `$this->_data['post_id']`, but returns only the first record found.

#### Update

The class you posted extends

```
Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
```

which in turn extends

```
Varien_Object
```

in a standard Magento OOB.

The `Varien_Object` class defines the standard getters/setters I was talking about, so yes, you can also use `$this->getPostId()` to get the value.

To understand how these getters/setters work, I'd recommend to check the `Varien_Object` and read about PHPs [magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php), like `__call()`, `__get()` and `__set()`.

Comment: it's using in  AheadWorks blog extension.

Comment: Please post the code of this `post.php` file, if the license allows it.

Comment: i post all the code in the post.php on the question, thank you

Comment: could i use $this->getPId() to replace $this->_data['post_id'];

Comment: To use `$this->getPId()` you'd have to write your own getter method.

Comment: but why $this->_data['post_id']; is ok, there is no  write a getter method

Comment: You don't need a getter for `$this->_data['post_id']`, because `AW_Blog_Model_Post` extends `Varien_Object`. That means it inherits all public and protected properties of `Varien_Object` and `_data` is a protected property of `Varien_Object`, so it's visible to `AW_Blog_Model_Post` and can be accessed directly. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php.